# How to sparsify a matrix/array in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a simple "matrix" in python that I would like to sparsify:

```
np.array([[5.72756493, 0.        , 0.        ],
          [2.86378246, 4.96021673, 0.        ],
          [5.72756493, 3.30681115, 2.33826859]])
```

I would like to reduce it to the following form:

```
np.array([[5.72756493, 0.        , 0.        ],
          [2.86378246, 4.96021673, 0.        ],
          [0.,         3.30681115, 2.33826859]])
```

I'm certain there must be some simple function in numpy/scipy that can handle this. I will only be working with small 3x3 matrices, so it needn't be the most optimized method

I want something like:
[image]

Comment: What exactly is the transformation rule? I don't see it from your example.

Comment: https://blog.smola.org/post/1016514759/sparsifying-a-vectormatrix Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Looks like the only rule here is to remove any duplicated items?

Comment: I want to find the 'most orthogonal' representation of the matrix. But, with the caveat that the only allowed operation is addition/subtraction of the first two rows by integer multiples. I thought the name for this was sparisification.

Comment: You need to express your caveats more clearly. i.e. am I allowed to only subtract line 1 from line 2, but line 1 and line 2 from line 3 etc.? Try to express your transform as a matrix of unknowns and the ambiguities will immediately be visible. You'll likely come up with a lower triangle matrix, and if you do [this might be a solution to your problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2876283/solve-matrix-least-squares-frobenius-norm-problem-with-lower-triangular-matrix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick web search shows that `sparsification` is an active computer science research area.  Apparently the idea is to make a matrix computationally more efficient by increasing the proportion of zeros.  This is done by zeroing out some some low magnitude terms, and doing some sort of sampling of the other terms.  But the matrix has to be 'computationally equivalent'.

There's nothing like this in `numpy`.  `scipy` has a `sparse matrix` package.  It can make a sparse matrix from a 2d `numpy` array, regardless of how many 0s it has.  But there's no `sparsifying` function.  In my experience `scipy.sparse` matrices are computationally efficient only if the sparsity is on the order of 10% or less (90% zeros).

Someone may have written sparsification code in Python, but it isn't part of these standard packages.

I'll vote for closing.

Answer (score -1):

use functions present in scipy https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html

Comment: There is no indication in the question, that OP actually wants sparse matrices. I think he is just using an uncommon term for some transformation, see the example he gave.